# Sorting by second element of split array in liquid

Tags: sorting, liquid

I am new to Liquid, so forgive me if this is obvious.

I have some data whose titles are prefixed with A1, B10, C64, etc. before the real text I want to sort on, for example, "A1 Something" "B10 Nothing" "A23 Another".

If I use

```
{% assign itemssorted = product.ds_related_products | sort: 'title' %}
{% for item in itemssorted %}
```

then I get the items sorted according to the prefixes, whereas what I *want* is the items sorted by the text *after* the prefixes.

Is there something like

```
{% assign itemssorted = product.ds_related_products | sort: 'title' | split: ' ' .... %}
```

I can use to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the sort:price for the variable you want to sort:

```
{% assign products = collection.products | sort: 'price' %}
{% for product in products %}
    <h4>{{ product.title }}</h4>
{% endfor %}

<!-- products = "a", "b", "A", "B" -->
{% assign products = collection.products | sort: 'title' %}
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure that I understand your approach - price has nothing to do with my sort requirements, I just want to strip some prefix text off the title property before sorting by the remaining title text, and was wondering whether I could do that in one statement in liquid?